# XCode - Swift Dynamic Options Area

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am new to programming in swift and xcode and cant find the correct terminology to try to find an answer to my issue. I need an area of a view to show different available settings based on a dropdown list in the UI. I though it might be a tab view controller, but it appears that they will take up an entire view instead of just a section of it. I then thought maybe a disclosure area, but am not sure if that is the correct control either. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: User36, Is this an iOS application or a macOS application? My answer was based on iOS. You put osx as a tag, but then mention tab view controller, which I thought was iOS exclusive. If this is for iOS, please update your tag. If it is just for macOS, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-controls/pickers/

In particular, `UIPickerView` is probably what you want.

Also, you can split up views into sub-views and such, if you wanted to :)

You can also use a `UITableView` if you have a lot of content.. see this answer for an example as an alternative:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/95734

more complexly, you could put a table view inside of a `UIScrollView` ..

so in all, I think the picker would the be easiest route to go for now :)